# Show the ContextMenuStrip on the correct location of ActiveX control

Tags: c#, winforms, contextmenustrip

I have an ActiveX control (VB 6.0) that I am using in C# and its right click "e" param has 
int e.x  and int e.y
now I want to show the contextmenustrip for this contorl. It is showing but not at the exact location that I right click the mouse, it is some point higher that where I do the right click.

I wrote something like this to fix the location problem,  did not fix it.

Thoughts?  what should I write to send the correct location to it?

```
m_contextPopup.Show(myActivexContorl.PointToClient(new Point(x, y)));
```

Comment: Ok I used PointToScreen   and it is working.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
m_contextPopup.Show(
    myActivexContorl,
    myActivexContorl.PointToClient( Form.MousePosition ) );
```